# Tabbar icons issue

Tags: iphone, icons, tabbar

My application is a tab bar based app, I have 5 tabs each of which requires to have a customized
image for the icon. I tried loading the image for each of the tabs, and it works. The problem is 
 I see a greyish circle for one of the icons, instead of a football image. Each of these images are
in .png i.e transparent. The football art is basically black & white like any football, the image
loads but I see a circle that has a solid grey color.  I tried extracting the image from the PSD 
several times. I am not sure if I need to tweak images in the interface builder or photoshop? please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Toolbar and tab bar icons are created just from the alpha channel of an image. If you want to provide different shades of grey, your image file must contain these shades in the alpha channel (i.e., set the opacity of the pixels to something between 0% and 100%).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion ole Begemann but I have tried that out many times, we tried switching to different modes like  grayscale, alpha channels, 8 bit modes...etc...Iam still not getting the required image....,,,